# Session scope JSF bean not present in HttpServletRequest in filter mehod

Tags: maven, jsf-2, tomcat7, richfaces, myfaces

I'm developing a web app with Richfaces and Apache MyFaces JSF implementation, Spring, Hibernate, deployed on a Tomcat 7.

Every one of my request goes through an authentication filter, which checks if the user is logged in. The problem is, that when I'm trying to load my login page, it gets stuck in the doFilter method, because the http servlet request session does not contain my login bean and when I try to get it, it's null.

After trying to load the page, the browser says: "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Here's my AuthenticationFilter:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ro.nordicparts.odin.frontend.managedbeans.Login;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter("/views/*")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    private FilterConfig config;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("AuthFilter doFilter");

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        Login auth = (Login) req.getSession().getAttribute("login");

        if (auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is logged in, so just continue request.
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            // Also check ajax requests, these need a special redirect response
            if ("partial/ajax".equals(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
                res.setContentType("text/xml");
                res.getWriter()
                    .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                    .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            } else {
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        config = null;
    }
}
```

And here's my LoginBean:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ro.nordicparts.odin.model.jaxb.LoginResponse;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;


@ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped
public class Login implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Login.class);

    public static final String AUTH_KEY = "app.user.name";

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionData}")
    private SessionData sessionData;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2156313213089107389L;

    public Login() { }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return sessionData.getLoginResponse() != null;
    }

    public String logoutAction() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                .remove(AUTH_KEY);
        sessionData.setLoginResponse(null);
        return "/login.xhtml";
    }

    public String loginAction() {
        ILoginBO bo = (ILoginBO) ServiceFactory.getServiceImpl(LoginBO.class);

        try {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = loginBO.loginAction(username, password);
            LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
            sessionData.setLoginResponse(loginResponse);
        } catch (NotAuthorizedException e) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String value = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msg['"+e.getMessage()+"']}", String.class);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(value);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            return "login.xhtml";
        }
        return "views/index.xhtml";
    }

    public String registerAction() {
        return "register.xhtml";
    }

    public SessionData getSessionData() {
        return sessionData;
    }

    public void setSessionData(SessionData sessionData) {
        this.sessionData = sessionData;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

login.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">


<h:head>
    <title><h:outputText value="#{msg['login.title']}" /></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"bhref="#{request.contextPath}/style/style2.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="container">
        <h:form class="login">
            <fieldset>
                <LEGEND>Login</LEGEND>

                <p>
                    <h:messages />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h:outputLabel class="field" for="username" value="#{msg['login.username']}" />
                    <h:inputText class="textboxright" id="username" value="#{login.username}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h:outputLabel class="field" for="password" value="#{msg['login.password']}" />
                    <h:inputSecret class="textboxright" id="password" value="#{login.password}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h:commandButton class="login" value="#{msg['login.loginAction']}"  action="#{login.loginAction}" />

                    <h:commandLink class="left" value="#{msg['login.registerAction']}" action="#{login.registerAction}" />
                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

If it helps in finding the problem, I'll also attach my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="norducparts-frontend" version="2.5">
    <display-name>NordicpartsFrontend</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ro.nordicparts.odin.frontend.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ro/nordicparts/odin/frontend/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ro/nordicparts/odin/config/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>views/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And also my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>odin</artifactId>
        <groupId>ro.nordicparts</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.nordicparts</groupId>
    <artifactId>odin.frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <name>odin.frontend</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <richfaces.version>4.3.5.FINAL</richfaces.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.tools.version>3.2.0.beta8</hibernate.tools.version>
        <hibernate.generic.dao>1.2.0</hibernate.generic.dao>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <jersey.version>1.1.5</jersey.version>
        <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
        <modules.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</modules.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${richfaces.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>odin.model</artifactId>
            <version>${modules.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>odin.business</artifactId>
            <version>${modules.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>odin.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${modules.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>odin.config</artifactId>
            <version>${modules.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
            <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oscache</groupId>
            <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>proxool</groupId>
            <artifactId>proxool</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
            <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
          </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>swarmcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>swarmcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.0RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>NordicpartsFrontend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Could you guys please help me out with this problem? I have been struggling with it for days and just can't seem to sort it out.

Comment: Aren't you redirecting a page to itself? If you're already requesting `login.xhtml` there should be no redirect.

Comment: Yes, I can see your point, but if the LoginBean would be there in the session attributes, it wouldn't be a problem, because it would continue on the filter chain and get to load the page.